How do I know if an Apple-account-login window is official or mimicked by the app?
I wanted to purchase a subcription of an APP on my mac.
But a Apple login ui prompted out and I had no idea whether it is a fake login window mimicked by the app or an official login window. How should I trust this kind of window?
Note:

Window titles are customizable.
The email is pre-filled



Get the app from a trusted source, like the app store, only after checking out reviews for the app. Make sure you have good antiviral software running and that it has verified the product.

Imma answer my question.

Go to mac settings and turn on use touch ID to purchase.
Go to appstore and download a random app and sign in with password for once.
Touch ID should be enabled now. U can download another random app to test.
Go to the app and purchase again. No password needed. If it needs pw, then maybe it is fake.

